# Error installing gem thinreports-rails on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install the gem thinreports-rails on my pc,  It has windows 10 installed. But when I ran the instruccion gem install thinreports-rails I got the next error

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (index.tlf, C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thinreports-rails-0.3.0/test/test_app/app/views/orders/no_set_layout.tlf)

please I will apriciate any comment about how resolve it error.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as message from error it deals with permission, 
Running the terminal as Administrator user will solve this problem, you can right click the the terminal / command prompt, then choose run as administrator, then try to run the command again

Comment: Thank you very much,  this fix my issue.